# Kibana / Solr Lucene Search Exclude strings ending in $

Tags: lucene, kibana

For whatever reason, I can't seem to exclude records where a specific field contains strings ending in a dollar sign ($). I know $ is an end of line character so I escaped it, but this did not do anything. I continue to get these records in my result despite adding:

```
AND NOT FieldName:*\$
```

I've also tried:

```
AND NOT FieldName:/.*\$/
```

And other variations. None of them eliminate it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`$` is not a special character for lucene query syntax: https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters

Try using it as is.